# Reading ADC value on a button press

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, analog, stm32, adc

I have a keypad matrix that outputs the voltage level based on the button pressed. Normally, it outputs a maximum voltage (3.3V) and at the press of the button, it outputs the corresponding voltage level based on the voltage dividers (from 0 - 3.3V.)

What I want to do is instead of constantly reading the ADC to determine which button was pressed, I want an interrupt to be generated when the button is pressed and then start the ADC conversion so I only have to enable the ADC when a button was pressed. Currently, I have ADC in continuous mode, an interrupt is generated when ADC conversion gets completed and I have an if statement to check that if the value is not 3.3V, then I process the data for the button press. This, I believe, is not an efficient way of doing this. The keypad schematics are added below.

[image: Keypad]

Comment: what keypad matrix is it?

Comment: What you suggest might not be possible. Show the schematics and tell which exact MCU you use. Also tell what part of the schematics you can change and what you can't change.

Comment: @Justme I have updated the post, please check. I am using STM32, the PCB is designed already so if there is a minor change that can solve the problem, than surely I can modify it.

Comment: @Juraj I have a custom Keypad with voltage dividers

Comment: Both ends of the switches have varying voltage so you can't genrerate button interrupts with diodes or something. But don't use continuous mode ADC then, only read ADC when you are checking if a button is pressed and if a button press should be handled. You did not say which exact STM32 model you are using, so it might be possible to have ADC in a mode where it gives an interrupt when voltage goes below a set level.

Comment: I am using STM32F407 specifically in this project

Comment: You should read the voltage twice to be sure that you didn't just hit a voltage gradient.

Answer (score 1):

As an informational commentary on the keypad design in the question I wanted to indicate that there could be some issues to deal with. I made a spreadsheet to calculate the nominal switch detect voltages for each switch:

[image]

In this setup it can be seen that the nominal differences in voltages for Row 3 switches ranges about 30mV. Row 2 is a little better at about 60mV or so.

Considerations:

1. Make sure to use at least 1% resistor values.
2. Make sure to have an A/D channel able to read the 3.3V so that the switch readings can be scaled ratiometrically from the actual 3.3V value.
3. Might be a good idea to make a more fully parameterized spreadsheet so it is possible to play with the resistor values to see if the delta voltages can be made a little larger (especially for the upper row).
4. This application certainly asks for usage of at least an A/D converter with 10-bits resolution. 12-bits would be even better.
5. This voltage divider type of keypad can be nearly impossible to correctly identify the proper switch pressed when more than one switch is pressed at the same time.

UPDATE

A much better way to implement a matrix switch array that is meant to be monitored via an A/D channel is to use a circuit like that shown below. Instead of using a simple resistor for the pullup use a simple current source constructed with a PNP transistor, two diodes and two additional resistors.

[image]

Note that the whole series of voltage generators down the left side are only placed in the circuit to allow the simulation to "press" each switch in the matrix in turn.

With the use of the current source the selection of resistors around the switch matrix becomes really easy and much more intuitive. With the resistor values shown in the simulation circuit it is possible to achieve almost a uniform delta for the A/D reading from switch to switch of almost 200mV. The uniformity makes it very much easier to write the detection software and apply an acceptance range around the A/D reading for each switch. Here is a waveform showing the VOUT from the circuit for each of the twelve switches.

[image]

A last big improvement here is that the current flow through the switch contacts is about 2mA. This provides the needed wiping current to help keep the switch resistance low.

Answer (score 0):

The STM32F407 ADC has an analog watchdog mode that generates an interrupt when a set threshold is crossed. You can use that to detect change from idle state to a button press.

You can also stop using continuous mode and check the buttons slower. For example in main code when you are anyway checking if something needs to be done based on button press, or use a timer interrupt to trigger a single conversion.

There are likely multiple other ways too. It depends how your code works and how much you want to change it.

Comment: Actually, the code is reading the data from multiple peripherals and then sending data to non-standard SPI interface LCD. This non-standard inteface needs the clock and data signals generated from GPIO manually. So, while I am writing to the LCD or reading data from Bluetooth App, I don't want to miss the button press. After a Button presss is detected, things are easier, however, I don't want to do polling as in that case most of the time will get wasted also single conversion mode is of not much use as I don't know when the button will be pressed, maybe once in a day ?

Comment: Then use the analog watchdog. But there is no way to detect button press except for letting the ADC sample the voltage and then making something look at the result. But you don't have to generate an ADC interrupt continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Set the timer to generate ADC event every for example 20ms. This event triggers ADC conversion and DMA transfer. When DHA has finished transmitting generate full transition DMA interrupt. Read the memory and check if something was pressed.Then inform your code (by event callback or sending to the queue if you use RTOS) that button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Most microcontrollers let you generate an interrupt when an IO pin changes state.  If that's possible on your processor, then you can connect an analog comparator to the analog output of your keypad signal and connect the comparator output to a digital IO pin on the processor.  When the keypad voltage goes below the comparator threshold (say 3.2V) the comparator output will change, and you will get an interrupt.

Just about any cheap comparator will work because your application has very loose accuracy and speed requirements compared to the capability of most comparators.  The only real design requirement is that the comparator can run from a 3.3V supply and can accept input voltage values very close to the positive supply.

Comment: Adding extra hardware is not needed. My answer explained that the MCU ADC has an analog watchdog mode which can be already implemented with no hardware changes at all, but by configuring the ADC to interrupt when the value crosses a threshold.

Comment: @Justme I am unfamiliar with the specifics of that microcontroller, so I offered a generic solution using a comparator.  If the built in ADC can do the compare function automatically and generate an interrupt, then the OP can certainly choose your solution.